# Find and remove specific files in folders and subfolders with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, windows-console

My problem is that my code works when it is directly executed in the windows console, but don't work when executing the bat-file. I think that the line 6 is the problem. Thanks for any answer

```
ECHO OFF
ECHO Suppresion des fichiers dans les dossiers et sous-dossiers avec l'extension .pdf
d:
cd D:\Users\moursa\Documents\Mes ecrits\Manuscrit\roque-phdthesis-template\images
:: Remove files in folders and subfolders with the name "*.pdf"
FOR /F "delims=" %a in ('DIR /b/s *.pdf') do echo DEL /f "%a"
ECHO END
PAUSE
EXIT
```

Comment: Open a command prompt window, type `for /?` and read the first few lines...

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to add a second `%` in front of `%a`, because the FOR function is different for a batch file.

```
ECHO OFF
ECHO Suppresion des fichiers dans les dossiers et sous-dossiers avec l'extension .pdf
d:
cd D:\Users\moursa\Documents\Mes ecrits\Manuscrit\roque-phdthesis-template\images
:: Remove files in folders and subfolders with the name "*.pdf"
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('DIR /b /s *.pdf') do echo DEL /f "%%a"
ECHO END
PAUSE
EXIT
```